# Run pipeline if the branch starts with - Regexp

Tags: regex, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to run the pipeline in gitlab only when the commit is from the branch where it starts with Feature or Bug. I tried with the following and its not working.

Can you please help me.

**`($CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME ==/^Feature(.?)*/ || $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == /^Bug(.?)*/)`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG =~ /^feature/'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG =~ /^bug/'
```